# How to export csv file with shift-jis encoding in laravel?

Tags: laravel, csv, laravel-5.7, laravel-excel

I am using [laravel-excel](https://laravel-excel.com/) to export csv file. To export, the code is like below,

```
 return Excel::download(new Export(results,$header), "test.csv");
```

And the Export.php file is like,

```
namespace App\AllClass;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class Export implements FromCollection,WithHeadings
{
    private $myArray;
    private $header;

    public function __construct($myArray,$header){
        $this->myArray = $myArray;
        $this->header = $header;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        $data = mb_convert_encoding($this->myArray,"SJIS", "UTF-8");
        // dump($data);
        return collect($data);
    }


    public function headings(): array
    {
        $header = mb_convert_encoding($this->header,"SJIS", "UTF-8");
        // dump($header);
        return $header;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am converting the data before creating excel. Without converting I can export perfectly in UTF-8 format. But after converting to shift-jis, it is deleting all Japanese character. However, if I dump the header before returning, it is showing me gibberish data; not empty string like the csv file.

Comment: Did you resolve it? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: No. This was an old project. I don't remember the details but later we decided to use PhpSpreadsheet. It was better than laravel excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved it.
Let's me share my solution here.
Laravel Excel not support it by default.
But we can do it by simple way.

1. Get csv content before download: \Excel::raw
2. Convert to another encoding: mb_convert_encoding
   https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html#storing-raw-contents
3. Download csv.

   $exportedObject= new \App\Exports\ClassExport($exportDataArray, $fileName);
   $csvContent = \Excel::raw($exportedObject, $exportedObject->writerType);

   $csvContent = mb_convert_encoding($csvContent, 'SJIS', 'auto');

   // In my case, I upload my csv to S3.
   $storageInstance = \Storage::disk('s3_import_csvs');
   $putFileOnStorage = $storageInstance->put($fileName, $csvContent);

Answer (score 0):

In config/excel.php, you should change CSV Settings

```php
'use_bom'                => true,
```

It's work well in Japanese