# How can I set encoding for export csv with Laravel Excel in Laravel

Tags: laravel, encoding, laravel-excel

I using Laravel Excel for export CSV file in Laravel.
How can I set the encoding for export csv file.

I have tried several ways:

1. Change config in `excel.php`

   ```php
   'use_bom' => false,
   ```
2. Use mb_convert_encoding to convert content to before export.

   ```php
   $exportData = mb_convert_encoding($exportData, "SJIS", "UTF-8");  
   $pblClassExport = new \App\Exports\PblClassExport($exportData, 'test.csv');
   ```

But it's not working. The encoding of csv file auto change by file content.

Comment: why you need to set ? encoding ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul
Thank for your response. 
I'm using a third-party service and the service required upload csv file has encoding is SJIS .

Comment: I posted your solution on answer section and made it community wiki. Feel free to edit and accept own solution.

Answer (score 1):

you need to configure your `PblClassExport.php` headers

in **PblClassExport.php**

```php
/**
 * Optional headers
*/
private $headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
    'Content-Encoding'=> 'SHIFT-JIS' // somthing like this ?
];
```

i have't done this but  i think it will work

ref link

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/exportables.html#exportables

---

### Update

you can encode line by line

```php
public function bindValue(Cell $cell, $value)
{
    $value = mb_convert_encoding($value, "SJIS");
    return parent::bindValue($cell, $value);
}
```

ref link https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/1886/552849170

Comment: thank for your answer. 

I tried to add it to header. But It's not working.  

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding

Comment: @ThanhNguyen i think you should use this https://github.com/SUKOHI/FluentCsv

Comment: Thank you so much!
I also tried it before, but I met the same issue with this issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60292152/how-to-export-csv-file-with-shift-jis-encoding-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

If you you use Laravel Excel 3.1, you can use `WithCustomCsvSettings` interface. Then you add your encoding setting in the `getCsvSettings` method like the following.

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomCsvSettings;
class InvoicesExport implements WithCustomCsvSettings
{
   public function getCsvSettings(): array
   {
        return [
            'output_encoding' => 'SJIS',
         ];

    }
}
```

Plese refer to the [docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/settings.html#available-csv-settings-settings) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it. Let's me share my solution here.

Laravel Excel not support it by default.But we can do it by simple way.

1. Get csv content before download: \Excel::raw
2. Convert to another encoding: mb_convert_encoding
   https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html#storing-raw-contents
3. Download csv.

   ```
   $exportedObject= new \App\Exports\ClassExport($exportDataArray, $fileName);  
   $csvContent = \Excel::raw($exportedObject, $exportedObject->writerType);


   $csvContent = mb_convert_encoding($csvContent, 'SJIS', 'auto');  

   // In my case, I upload my csv to S3.
   $storageInstance = \Storage::disk('s3_import_csvs');  
   $putFileOnStorage = $storageInstance->put($fileName, $csvContent);
   ```

<sub>Note: Solution povided by OP on question section.</sub>